# Display recent post by tag

Tags: recent-posts

I have 6 related posts by tag in every post. But some tags have only 2 or 3 posts. So in these posts, related posts section shows only 2 or 3 post.

I want to complete related posts (if not 6) with the new posts.

I tried many codes but if tags have 2 posts, than related posts show 2 post only. Can I add new posts to complete to 6?

Or can I display recent post order by same tag? So, there will be 6 posts and same tags will be shown first.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can try it. [Here!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12272997/wordpress-trying-to-get-posts-by-tag) Good luck for you :D

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried that but it shows only recent posts. It does not show posts with the same tag. I could not figure out what is the $brand_name.

Answer (score 1):

For a list, the code would look something like this:

```
<ul>
<?php $args = array(
  'tag' => 'travel', 
  'posts_per_page' => 3); ?>

  <?php $recent_posts = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

  <?php if ($recent_posts->have_posts()) : 
        while ($recent_posts->have_posts()) : $recent_posts->the_post();
   ?>


    <li><?php the_title(); ?></li>

  <?php endwhile; 

     else :
     echo "Nothing";
      endif;
      wp_reset_postdata();
  ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="page-loop">

    <?php
      while (have_posts()) : the_post();
        $page_title = strtolower(get_the_title());
        the_title('<h1>','</h1>');
      ?>
        <p><?php the_content(); ?><p>
    <?php endwhile;?>

</div>

<!-- Get the most recent post that has been tagged with the page title -->
<div class="related-posts">

    <?php
      $args = array(
        'tag' => $page_title,
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
      );
      $query = new WP_Query($args);
      if ($query->have_posts()) :
        while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
          the_title('<h1>','</h1>');
        ?>
        <p><?php the_content(); ?><p>
    <?php endwhile; else: ?>
      <p>Sorry, no posts with this tag!</p>
    <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>

</div>




/** register the meta box */
```

function my_theme_add_meta_boxes() {
    global $post;
    add_meta_box(
        'my-theme-meta',
        'Choose a tag',
        'my_theme_print_page_meta',
        'page',
        'normal',
        'high'
    );
}
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'my_theme_add_meta_boxes');

```
/** Add extra meta to the page */
function my_theme_print_page_meta() {
    global $post;
    $page_tags = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_page-tags', true);
    ?>
    <label for="page-tags">Add a 'tag'</label>
    <input type="text" class="page-tags" name="page-tags" value="<?php echo esc_attr($page_tags); ?>" />
<?php
```

}
/** Save post meta */
function my_theme_save_custom_meta() {
    global $post;

```
// Stops WP from clearing post meta when autosaving
if( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
  return $post->ID;
}
if (isset($_POST['page-tags'])) {
    $clean = sanitize_text_field($_POST['page-tags']);
    update_post_meta($post->ID, '_page-tags', $clean);
}
```

}
add_action('save_post', 'my_theme_save_custom_meta');

```
<div class="page-loop">

<?php
  while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    $page_tags = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_page-tags', true);
    the_title('<h1>','</h1>');
  ?>
    <p><?php the_content(); ?><p>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

$page_tags,
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
      );
      $query = new WP_Query($args);
      if ($query->have_posts()) :
        while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
          the_title('

## ','

');
        ?>

Sorry, no posts with this tag!

Comment: Dharmishtha, thanks so much. Is there any way to display new posts even there is no posts with same tag. Let's say I created new post with the tag NewTag. And there is no other posts with this tag. Then related posts section will display -Sorry, no posts with this tag!- Can't we display new posts if empty?